# How do I do about solving this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve the matrix equations $CYA = D$ in which
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2  \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad C = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2  \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
How do I solve it?
$$CYA = D \implies Y = D (CA)^{-1}$$
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $Y = C^{-1}\cdot D\cdot A^{-1}$

Comment: Hahah good hint, thats mean its correct, can you calculate it and show me that y = cda?

Comment: Find $C^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$. Then multiply in the order BRIC-Fan said.

Comment: ok i got y = (-3 -2 5), (5 3 -7) thank you for the help

Comment: No problem TJ....